# stream builder vs Bloc with event

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, stream-builder

the question is why we use Bloc with streams and bloc builder not streams and stream builder only ?
and i want to know can i use stream builder with stateless widget ? and stream builder` rebuild all build method or the widget that wrap it only?
and can i use bloc builder in stateless widget when i use controller ? if yes when should i close the controller ?

````
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)```
````

Comment: if you want to use bloc like stream you have to use bloc consumer, its listen all event of your state like stream

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc-library.html

Comment: the question is what is the main reason that make me use bloc not streams

Answer (score 0):

First, I want you to read [this](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocbuilder) from the bloc documentation.

> BlocBuilder is very similar to StreamBuilder but has a more simple API to reduce the amount of boilerplate code needed.

The `StreamBuilder` is based on `Stream, and the` BlocBuilder` is based on cubits and blocs which are similar to streams.

But the main goal of using the `Bloc` library in the first place is to achieve the BloC (Business Logic Component ) pattern which separates your project into layers, the presentation, business logic, and data layers.

This bloc library makes your project follows the BlocC pattern and no layer should know about the other, this will make your project more clean and maintainable to work with, edit, upgrade, and analyze...

Using `StreamBuilder`, all it can do is listen to a `Stream`, and build a widget-sub tree based on it as an example, your project logic will be inside your view, and in another place, there is the data layer, which leads to an absolute mess, now just imagine if you have an intermediate or big flutter project, and you wanted to change just the name of a method in some file, I'm pretty sure you will get lost before you will find it because your project does not follow any architecture.

using the `BlocBuilder` will give you same rebuilding functionalities as `StreamBuilder`, but your project will be well architectures and everything is organized, the presentation/view layer will now nothing about your logic and so on for the data layer.

Comment: i am already using clean architecture i have presentation layer,domain layer and data layer so the project already clean and organized and in presentation layer i have the view and view model so the logic is separated from the view by view model
in view model i wrote my business logic with streams and listen it in the view by stream builder

Comment: can you give us an example ?

Answer (score 0):

The **Bloc** is used to separate the **business logic** from UI layer, while stream is way to get stream of data. So, if you need a separate class which can handle the data then use Bloc, otherwise if you already have the Business logic class then you can use Stream directly.